# How to get the available properties and methods of a variable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I try to use `ts-morph` to analysis the object [instance](https://github.com/antvis/G6/blob/v5/packages/g6/src/index.ts#L9)'s available properties and methods.

```
const Graph = extend(EmptyGraph<{}, {}>, stdLib);  // I want to know `Graph` available properties and methods I can use from it.

export { Graph, stdLib };

export default { Graph, stdLib };
```

I tried `ts-morph` library to access the desired effect, but it only have [`Variable Declaration` and `Variable Statement` functions](https://ts-morph.com/details/variables).

so, is there any way to achieve my goal?

I think there must be have this function, because VSCode hover the variable `stdLib`, it shows the properties and methods of it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to check out [`@baileyherbert/reflection`](https://yarnpkg.com/package/@baileyherbert/reflection):

```
const { getMethods, getProperties } = new ReflectionClass(Graph);
const graphMetadata = {
  methods: getMethods().map(method => method.name),
  properties: getProperties()
}
```